# Linear order on the set N^N

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

Give the example of the Linear order on the set: $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$

I know that $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ and it's a string, but I'm unable to give an example.

Comment: Hint : There is an order on the alphabet $a,b,c,d,...,x,y,z$, and hence there is an order on words made out of $a,b,c,d,...,x,y,z$ which is reflected in the English dictionary, for example. Think about using this approach on your set : there is a natural order on $\mathbb N$, and it should lead to an ordering on $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, thanks for answering but haven't learned about the alphabet. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think that he just means the letters that we write with, not a mathematical term.  Do you know how to find a word in a dictionary based on your knowledge of the ABC?

Comment: What I am saying is this : for example if you have two strings $a_1a_2a_3...$ and $b_1b_2b_3...$ of natural numbers, which correspond to two elements of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$. You first compare $a_1$ and $b_1$ : if $a_1<b_1$ then the first string is smaller than the second string. If $a_1 > b_1$ then the first string is larger than the second string. If $a_1 = b_1$, then move to comparing $a_2$ and $b_2$ (repeat the above steps with $a_1,b_1$ replaced by $a_2,b_2$). If these are equal then move to $a_3$ and $b_3$. I hope you see how to compare the strings from here.

Comment: @badjohn, so, this set is a set of natural numbers strings, tell me if I'm wrong. So those would be sets of natural numbers, so how exactly do I use the alphabet there?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, oh, ok that seems to be right, so it's like building words amd comparing then due to lexicographical order?

Comment: @Karol Yes, it's like comparing words, but instead of letters you now have the natural numbers. This allows us to compare any two (countably)infinite strings of natural numbers.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, thank you very much, I think that now I know what to do.

Comment: Excellent. You may write an answer for your own question and close it.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, when I finish that I'll do it.

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote an answer while you two were commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, think of words in a dictionary: how do you order them?  Which comes first: Apple or Orange?  You compare the first letters and since A is before O, you say that Apple is before Orange.  If the first letters, are the same then compare the second so apple is before avocado.  If they are the same until one ends then you need a rule, e.g. the shorter one is first so grape is before grapefruit.

Your functions can be written as a list of numbers.  $f(1), f(2), f(3), ... $  To compare $f$ and $g$, compare $f(1)$ and $g(1)$.  If $f(1)$ is less then $f$ is less.  If they are the same then compare $f(2)$ and $g(2)$, etc.  Continue until you find a difference.

Comment: Thank you, just quick question. Is a linear order a lexicographical order?

Comment: I'd said the reverse.  A lexicographical order will be a linear but maybe not the reverse.

Comment: why is a lexicographical order a linear order? I cannot find any explanation and I'm beginning to understand it so I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: Well, because the procedure I described will satisfy the axioms of a linear order.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order